# Dataset shift adaptation and Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: probability, shift, vowpalwabbit

I'm currently playing around with Vowpal Wabbit. I'm particulary interested in how the tool handles dataset shifts. From my intuition this should be straight forward since VW is an online algorithm. Therefore I generated a test dataset with three features. The following dictionary contains the name of the feature and the probabiltiy of being postive or negative:

```
{"feat1" : 0.02, "feat2" : 0.3, "feat3" : 0.15}
```

Then I generate a toy dataset in the following way:

1. Uniformly randomly select one feature
2. Generate a class label 1 with the corresponding probabily and -1 otherwise
3. Generate about 100000 datasets/rows

The I learn on this dataset with Vowpal Wabbit with a command like this:

```
vw data/startdata.vw --bfgs --passes 10 --loss_function logistic  --compressed --cache_file data/toy.cache --final_regressor data/toy.model
```

My logloss and auc look something like this:

```
logloss = 0.0364034559032
auc = 0.624257973639
```

The probabilies that have been learn look like this:

```
feat1 : 0.0221759405605553977
feat2 : 0.3080836682440751833
feat3 : 0.1524675104299118037
```

The results are pretty accurate. 
Now I create another dataset with the following probabilities:

```
{"feat1" : 0.70, "feat2" : 0.80, "feat3" : 0.04}
```

So the probabilities of a feature belonging to a particualr class has shifted such that this essentially is dataset shift. Since this is of interest for me, I intentially include the old model now for the learning of the new dataset. That is:

```
vw data/nextdata.vw --bfgs --passes 10 --loss_function logistic  --compressed --cache_file data/toy.cache -i data/toy.model --final_regressor data/toy.model
```

But, instead of seeing some sort of adaptation I instead now get the following result:

```
logloss = 3.22754717189
auc = 0.456873489527
```

and the probailies for the features do not change after the second run:

```
feat1 : 0.0221759405605553977
feat2 : 0.3080836682440751833
feat3 : 0.1524675104299118037
```

So my conclusion is: Nothing is learned when including the old model in the second dataset learning. However, I would expect Vowpal Wabbit to adapt to the shift after some time. Obviously, this does not happen.

My Question: How do I have to tweak the vowpal wabbit parameters in order to adapt to such a dataset shift?

Comment: Note that you're asking vw to reuse the cache from the first data-set in the second call.  Do you still see the same problem if you don't specify `--cache_file data/toy.cache` in the second call?

Comment: More detail: since a cache is required for multi-pass, just replace the specific cache file with one auto-created by `vw` for the respective data-set. i.e. use `-c` but don't use a specific `--cache_file ...`

Comment: For online learning try `vw -d data/nextdata.vw -c -i data/toy.model -f data/nextdata.model --loss_function=logistic`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I delete the cache file before trying to learn on the `nextdata.vw` dataset.

Comment: I just checked what you proposed however, nothing did change the result. I delteted the cache file and then tried: `vw -d data/nextdata.vw --bfgs --passes 10 --loss_function logistic -c -i data/toy.model --decay_learning_rate 1 --initial_t 0  --power_t 0.5 -l 0.5 --final_regressor data/toy.model --compressed`

Comment: The best way to make sure that right cache file is always used is addition of -k parameter to vw command line. It will delete current cache for first pass and recreate it for further passes.
toom, if this problem is still reproducible, could you upload both vw files - i'll try to debug it.